# How to insert the record which contain double quote in a string to target | Informatica |

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have an issue in inserting data from file to target database in Informatica
The file separator used is `,`

File contain below data :

```
a,abc "tyu",ghj
avc,jk,ghjsjs "hjk",
```

Data base is not accepting entire record as one string for `abc "tyu"` and `ghjsjs "hjk"`

How to resolve this so that the data comes in double quote within the single comma separated

How to apply logic at expression level to resolve this issue

I have used replace but it replace `""` with null

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove optional quotes from source file property.
open infa session > go to mapping tab > then go to sources and select the source > then select file properties > And you will see advanced window like this screenshot

1. Once you click on advanced tab, it opens window.
2. Make sure optional quotes is selected as 'none'.
3. Press ok and save the session.

Run it to test.

[image]